# Extract alphabetic strings values from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

If have a list of different types of strings and from that I want to combine all the alphabetic strings in the list into one single value.

For example:

```
    ['000000001', 'Aaron', 'Appindangoye', '26', '183', '84.8']
```

Here, I want to get `Aaron Appindangoye` together.

Comment: Those aren't mixed data types, they are all strings. Do you want all the alphabetic strings?

Comment: How can you say mixed data types when everything is a string in your list?

Comment: How do you know you want to combine the names?

Comment: If you meant combining one with alphabets then, you may try: `' '.join(item for item in my_list if item.isalpha())`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access to the 2 names by index:

```
items = ['000000001', 'Aaron', 'Appindangoye', '26', '183', '84.8']

name = ' '.join(items[1:3])
print(name)
```

-> Aaron Appindangoye

See **list** in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)